# ReactJS - Get height of dynamic div with no css height defined

Tags: html, reactjs, height

I'm having some problem to get height of a dynamic created div. This div does not have css height property defined. I'm using React JS. I tried use jQuery, pure javascript and React tools to get DOM Node, but the result is always 0. If i try $(....).height() at console, the value is showed correctly. Anyone can help me? Thanks.

Comment: When are you reading the height()? can you provide some code?

Comment: I'm using it at componentDidMount, like this:  'componentDidMount: function () {

        console.info($('div.titleModal').outerHeight(true));''

Answer (score 1):

I've created a tiny fiddle to reproduce your issue and it's reading the height properly. Notice, that i'm using reacts `ref` attribute and `ReactDOM.findDOMNode()` to access the `<div>`.

https://jsfiddle.net/03ejh9yk/3/

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#reactdom.finddomnode

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the problems is with react life cycles. I created a new question about it. [ReactJS - ComponentDidMount is executing before render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35176172/reactjs-componentdidmount-is-executing-before-render)