# ReactJS - ComponentDidMount is executing before render

Tags: reactjs, synchronization

I´m having some problems with react. I´m using map function at render and the function componentDidMount is being called before it finish.

Here snippet of my code

```
componentDidMount: function() {
   console.info("didMount");
},
render: function() {
   return React.createElement("div", null, 
             this.state.fields.map(function(field) {
                console.info("field" + field);
                return React.createElement("span", null, field);
             }.bind(this)));
}
```

It being printed "didMount" before "field...". How can i solve this? It seems that map is async.

Thank´s

Comment: Are `this.state.fields` present in `componentDidMount`?

Comment: run your `map` outside `React.createElement` and include it then, just inside `render` callback

Comment: Have you an exemple of this, Oleg? this.state.fields contains a list of react components that i want add. Is it possible to create a React div with the elements at componentWillMount and then pass it to render as variable this.state.var ?

Answer (score 0):

How are you initializing your `this.state.fields`?  If you do it in the `componentDidMount` function, then `console.info("field" + field);` never gets executed because the field/array is null.

Use the [setState callback](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) parameter to run code after the state has been initialized/updated.

Comment: I'm using Redux to handle state.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Redux, but you can add a breakpoint to the [return React.createElement("div", null,] line and look at the value of this.state.fields.  My guess is that it's null or empty which is why you're not getting any corresponding console output.